# JPQL to Criteria

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, jpql

I have following classes:

```
@Embeddable Class A // (with field String x);
Class B // (with field @Embedded A a)
Class C // (with field @OneToOne B b);
```

I would like to create method `getAllByXs(List<String> xs)` using criteria to get all C entries where `c.b.a.x` is in `xs`

Typed query with content `SELECT c FROM C c JOIN c.b b WHERE b.a.x IN :param` works fine. How to write same query using Criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example criteria based query may look like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<C> cq = cb.createQuery(C.class);
Root<C> c = cq.from(C.class);
Join<C, B> b = c.join("b");
cq.select(c)
cq.where(b.get("a").get("x").in(cb.parameter(List.class, "param")));

List<C> = em.createQuery(cq)
            .setParameter("param", Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz"))
            .getResultList();
```